# Unable to do Renovate Installation Using Helm

Tags: kubernetes-helm, renovate

I am using official Helm charts for RenovateBot to run as a Cronjob and it should work with Self hosted Gitlab Repository https://github.com/renovatebot/helm-charts

Here is my values.yaml

```
renovate:
  enabled: true 

  image:  
    tag: "36.107.1"
  platform: gitlab

  gitlab:
    url:  "https://gitlab.apps.abc.hodomain.local/"
    privateToken: "git-renovate-token"
  

  cronjob:
    schedule: "* * * * * "
    concurrencyPolicy: Forbid
```

But getting error

`abc@IN-MRP6T0V6YW chart % helm upgrade --install renovate . -n ddcdevopstools --dry-run Release "renovate" does not exist. Installing it now. Error: execution error at (renovatebot/charts/renovate/templates/config.yaml:20:8): A valid .Values.renovate.config entry is required if existingConfigFile is not specified!`

Can someone suggest best way to easily deploy renovte which work with self host Gitlab and for all repos . Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the problem quite clearly through this message

```
A valid .Values.renovate.config entry is required if existingConfigFile is not specified!
```

The `.Values.renovate.config` parameter is required and you cannot leave it blank. So, your `values.yaml` config file will look like this

```
renovate:
  enabled: true 
  config: "<enter your value>"
...
```

Or you can omit `required` function from the helm template file.

More details [here](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-required-function).